Java: Identifying new lines of a rolling logfile
I have to periodically (every second) a logfile from a Java application and parse new lines. The file is rolling by its size (.log -> .log.1).
Is there a lightweight lib that does the job of giving me every new line?
I do not like to implement the logic of "already seen" vs. "new" in combination with the rolling file.

RandomAccessFile. Seek to the end. When the size has increased, read between newSize-oldSize and newSize

Err, BufferedReader.readLine()? If you get a null, sleep one second and retry.
